# How do I configure the sort order of results returned by DBSet local?

Tags: entity-framework-5

I want to be able to configure the sort order of a binding source based on DBSet<> local
By passing the number of a field in the resultant query.

i.e order by the nth field in the query.

I am guessing I would be needing to use the .OrderBy() method, but dont know what to pass into it.

I know that I need 
Here is the code that sets up the binding source.

```
var dset = base.Context.Organisations;
if (QuickSearch == null) QuickSearch = "";  
var qry = dset.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(QuickSearch));
qry.Load();
bindingSource.DataSource = dset.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code may help-

_bindingSource.Sort = "ColumnName ASC";

OR

_bindingSource.Sort = "ColumnName DESC";

OR

_bindingSource.Sort = "ColumnName1 ASC, ColumnName2 DESC";

and so on......